# Abstract Generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class :

```
public abstract class Step {
    public abstract <S,T> S makeAStep(S currentResult, T element);
}
```

and I'm trying to Implement it so it will take two int's and return the sum of them , something like this :

```
public class sumOfInts extends Step {
    public <Integer,Integer> Integer makeAStep(Integer currentResult, Integer element){
        return currentResult + element;
    }
}
```

but I get the following error :

> The type sumOfInts must implement the inherited abstract method Step.makeAStep(S, T)

please help me (I need it for my programming languages course homework)

I asking very kindly to write me a code that does what I want to accomplish which wont 
have any errors or warnings 
thanks in front

Comment: Because it's working now, I suggest you accept the answer that was most useful to you, possibly giving up votes to answers that were useful at all.

Answer (score 15):

```
public abstract class Step<S,T> {
    public abstract S makeAStep(S currentResult, T element);
} 

public class SumOfInts extends Step<Integer,Integer> {
    // etc.
```

Comment: Also, the Step class itself would have to have the generics registered at the class level for this suggestion to work, not at the method level

Comment: @Jason +1 I agree! I think your comment corresponds to the answer I just wrote.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Jonathan's answer.

---

There is also another possibility, given below, that **keeps the type parameters on the method itself**.

It's only theory in this case, because the class and method names suggest that this has no meaning for this example.
So I change the names for my example:

```
    public abstract class Step {
      public abstract <S,T> String makeAStep(S first, T second);
    }

    public class ConcatTwo extends Step {
      public <S, T> String makeAStep(S first, T second){
        return String.valueOf(first) + String.valueOf(second);
      }
    }
```

> Note : This works because the operation uses `String.valueOf(Object)`, that works for any type (all subclass Object). For another operation, we would have to restrict S and T, using something like
>   `S extend Integer` for example.